# Why is a single backslash shown when using quotes

Tags: bash, escape-characters, echo

I always thought that bash treats backslashes the same when using without or with double quotes, but I was wrong:

```
[user@linux ~]$ echo "foo \ "
foo \
[user@linux ~]$ echo foo \ # Space after \
foo
```

So I thought backslashes are always printed, when using double quotes, but:

```
[user@linux ~]$ echo "foo \" "
foo "
[user@linux ~]$ echo "foo \\ "
foo \
```

Why is the backslash in the first code line shown?

Comment: Similar: [Why does dash expand \\\\ differently to bash?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321422)

Comment: Or: [Echo new line and string beginning \t](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/348786)

Comment: `echo foo \ ` is equivalent to `echo foo " "`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Section [3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) of the [GNU Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) says:

> The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of
>   the following characters: ‘`$`’, ‘`` ` ``’, ‘`"`’, ‘`\`’, or
>   `newline`. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one
>   of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters
>   without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be
>   quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If
>   enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ‘`!`’ appearing
>   in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding
>   the ‘`!`’ is not removed.

Thus `\` in double quotes is treated differently both from `\` in single quotes and `\` outside quotes. It is treated literally except when it is in a position to cause a character to  be treated literally that could otherwise have special meaning in double quotes.

Note that sequences like `\'`, `\?`, and `\*` are treated literally and the backslash is  not removed, because `'`, `?` and `*` already have no special meaning when enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 6):

Backslash is interpreted differently according context:

- Within double quotes (your first example):

  ```
  The backslash  retains its special meaning  only when followed
  by one of the following characters: $, `, ", \, or <newline>.
  ```
- Without quotes (your second example):

  ```
  A  non-quoted  backslash  (\)  is the  escape  character.   It
  preserves  the  literal  value  of  the  next  character  that
  follows,  with the  exception of  <newline>.  If  a \<newline>
  pair  appears, and  the backslash  is not  itself quoted,  the
  \<newline> is treated  as a line continuation (that  is, it is
  removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).
  ```
- Using the construct `$'....'`, where you can use inside the quote the standard backspace character, nearly as in C. e.g. `\n`, `\t`, etc.
- Using backquotes:

  ```
  When  the old-style  backquote form  of substitution  is used,
  backslash retains its literal  meaning except when followed by
  $, `, or \.
  ```

*Source of quotes: bash manual*

Comment: Some of the text that you quoted has been misinterpreted during the conversion from markdown, resulting in missing words and characters.

Comment: In this case, I would just quote the manpage as code, avoiding this whole class of issues. (There is some mangling left, I will submit an edit to fix this.)

Comment: @dhag Although I don't think manpage quotes usually look better as code, I'm glad you've re-edited it, because I now see that I introduced mistakes in my own edit (I turned `\<newline>` into `<newline>`) which harmed the post, and which your edit fixes. Sorry about that, and thanks!

Comment: @EliahKagan: No problem. I agree that code isn't the proper way to quote text, but it's sometimes the easiest way to avoid breaking anything :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 'complicated for the sake of understanding' example. Hopefully it'll be helpful for anyone else trying to understand qutoes and backslashes.

In the example here, I want to repeat the pattern 3 times.

```
>~# echo 'ABC\n\t'
ABC\n\t
```

Using **single quotes**, it is fairly straightforward:

```
>~# echo 'ABC\n\t' | sed -e 's#ABC\\n\\t#ABC\\n\\tABC\\n\\tABC\\n\\t#'
                                  ↑  ↑      ↑        ↑  ↑     ↑  ↑
                    # These backslashes escaped by sed
ABC\n\tABC\n\tABC\n\t
```

Here is the way to do it using **double quotes**: (again, complicated just for the sake of understanding)

```
>~# echo 'ABC\n\t' | sed -e "s#ABC\\\n\\\t#$(printf '%0.sABC\\\\n\\\\t' $(seq 1 3))#"
                                  ↑   ↑                     ↑ ↑  ↑ ↑
            # These backslashes are removed in double quotes. Showing intermediate stage:

>~# echo 'ABC\n\t' | sed -e "s#ABC\\n\\t#$(printf '%0.sABC\\n\\t' $(seq 1 3))#"

                # Expanding printf results in:

>~# echo 'ABC\n\t' | sed -e 's#ABC\\n\\t#ABC\\n\\tABC\\n\\tABC\\n\\t#'

ABC\n\tABC\n\tABC\n\t
```

Just to play around and master quotes and backslashes, replace the single quotes around printf with double quotes.